# Random flipping of sub-menu when hover it

Tags: jquery, html, css

With my code below I created a `<header>` consisting of an `<image>` and a `<navigation>`. All this works perfectly so far.

Now, the `1.0 Main Menu` consists of a `Sub-Menu` that **SlideDown** once you hover it.

Most of the time this SlideDown function works without any issue but **every now and then** the `Sub-Menu` somehow **keeps flipping back and force**. This mainly happens when you go with the mouse on the `1. Main Menu` and then you move the cursor **immediately** to the `1.3 Menu`.

It is very difficult to explain this behaviour because it does not happen always but I hope you can see it in my code.

You can also find my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vu0hnqab/16/).

What do I have to change in my code to avoid this random flipping of the `Sub-Menu`?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children(".SlideItem").slideDown(500);
  });
  $(".button").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children(".SlideItem").slideUp(500);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}

.header {
 width: 80%;
 height: 10%;
 margin-left: 10%; 
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color: yellow;
}

.image {
 width: 30%;
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align:center;
 align-items: center;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color: green;
}

.navigation {
 width: 70%;
 height: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
}

.navigation > ul {
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color: blue;
}

.navigation > ul > li  {
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align:center;
 align-items: center;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
}

.content{
 width: 80%;
 margin-top: 10%; 
 margin-left: 10%; 
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color: red;
}

.SlideItem {
 display: none;
}

.button {
 position: relative;
}

.SlideItem {
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: lime;
}

.SlideItem li {
  display:block; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"> 

      <div class="image">
      Image
      </div>
  
      <nav class="navigation"> 
        <ul>
          <li class="button"> 1.0 Main Menu 
            <ul class="SlideItem">
              <li> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
              <li> 1.2 Sub Menu </li>
              <li> 1.3 Sub Menu </li>     
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li> 2.0 Main Menu </li>
          <li> 3.0 Main Menu </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      
</div>
```

Comment: I think it's because that the speed of your slideDown and slideUp can't follow with the mouse. So if you moving the mouse very quickly over the 1.0 Main Menu several times, thats why it's keep slide down and up.

Comment: Is there something like a "standard" speed that is normally used for such menus?

Comment: It's because the behaviour of slideDown like @RasmusGlenvig said.

Comment: @Miguel Morera: How can I avoid it but still be able to use the SlideDown-Animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of `js` for simple dropdown, you can make it with pure css only.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.navigation {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.navigation>ul {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.navigation>ul>li {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.content {
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
}

.SlideItem {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: lime;
  max-height:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition: max-height .5s linear;
}

.button:hover .SlideItem {
  max-height: 100px;
}

.SlideItem li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="image">Image</div>
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li class="button"> 1.0 Main Menu
        <ul class="SlideItem">
          <li> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
          <li> 1.2 Sub Menu </li>
          <li> 1.3 Sub Menu </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> 2.0 Main Menu </li>
      <li> 3.0 Main Menu </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Abhishek, thanks a lot for this great code. Is there also a way to make the animation in the CSS exactly the same as in the jQuery because right now it animates slightly different?

Comment: @Michi I have updated my answer, check once, I have used `max-height` for `transition`

Comment: Hi Abhishek, thanks for all your effort. I used your first code to further develop my menu (I added more sub-menus) which gave me the perfect result here: https://jsfiddle.net/vu0hnqab/37/ When I use your revised code with the transition max-height I could not make the sliding work for the additional sub-menus here: https://jsfiddle.net/vu0hnqab/39/ Well this is not part of this question anymore so I leave it to you if you wanna help me out with this as well. I will give you the answer as correct anyways.

Comment: Maybe you can help me out here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810332/sub-sub-menus-do-not-appear