# Bars inside mobile menu button do not appear in vertical center

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

With the code below I created a mobile menu button `.container` inside my `.navigation`. All this works fine so far.

However, I want that the `.bars` inside the mobile menu button to be vertically centered. I tried to go with `vertical-align: center;` but could not make it work.

What do I have to change in my code so the `.bars` in the mobile menu button `.container` get vertically centered?

You can also find my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p6dqLLj6/16/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 30%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.container {
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 cursor: pointer;
 float: right;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color: fuchsia;
}

.bars {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 vertical-align: center;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
 height: 10%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #333;
 margin-top: 8%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> 

 <div class="image">
 Image
  </div>
  
  <nav class="navigation"> 
  
    <div class="container">
      <div class="bars">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    
  </nav>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Comment: vertical-align: center; does not exist. Should be vertical-align: middle;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are already using `flexbox`, add the following styles to `bars`:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
```

and add `margin: 4% 0` for the `bar1`,`bar2` and `bar3`

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 30%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: fuchsia;
}

.bars {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 4% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="image">
    Image
  </div>
  <nav class="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="bars">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: @Michi cool, could you please upvote and finish the question too, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, but I have to wait 3 minutes.

Comment: Do you think you also have an idea for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810332/sub-sub-menus-do-not-appear

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:flex`

```
.bars {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: and remove margin from your .bar child

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use `display: flex;` on `.bars`; Then `flex-direction: column;` and `justify-content: center;`

```
.bars {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;

 /* new stuff here: */
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

This will work, but the bars won't look quite right because `.bar1` has a `margin-top` of `8%`. If you only apply `margin-top` to `.bar2` and `.bar3` then it will look right.

```
.bar2, .bar3 {
  margin-top: 8%;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 30%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.container {
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 cursor: pointer;
 float: right;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color: fuchsia;
}

.bars {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 
 /* new stuff here: */
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
 height: 10%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #333;
}
.bar2, .bar3 {
  margin-top: 8%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> 
 <div class="image">
 Image
  </div>
  <nav class="navigation"> 
    <div class="container">
      <div class="bars">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```